# Spring AOP: After or AfterReturning which advice will invoked first

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop

Suppose we applied two advice one is type **After** and another of type **AfterReturning** on the same **jointpoint**(business function) then which **advice** will invoke first if the **jointpoint** executes successfully

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Invocation of the advices of different type applied on the same jointpoint(core business related modules) as follows :

> 1.Around
>
> 2.Before and/or After
>
> 3.AfterReturning or AfterThrowing

Suppose we applied **all five types** of advices on the same jointpoint then the flow will be like :

> 1. **Around** type advice will be invoked and code before `pjp.proceed()` of Around type advice will be executed where **pjp** is the reference
>      variable of **ProceedingJoinPoint** **interface**.
> 2. **Before** type advice will be invoked and executed fully.
> 3. code inside **jointpoint** will be executed fully.
> 4. Code after `pjp.proceed()` of **Around** type advice will be executed if **jointpoint** executes successfully otherwise skip this step and go to
>      step 5. If it's modified **return value** then this **new return value** will
>      be effected to the followings **advice** or **method** invocation.
> 5. **After** type advice will be invoked and executed fully.
> 6. **AfterReturning** type advice will be invoked and executed fully if jointpoint executes successfully else if jointpoint throws any error
>      then **AfterThrowing** type advice will be invoked and executed fully.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than reiterating answer, here is a link to the Spring [AOP](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering) that describes the ordering.